# ¿Como capturar datos de mi filtro woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Buen día, necesito capturar los datos de mi filtro tal cual muestro en la imagen para que al momento de darle clic en el botón "encontrar producto" me los envié como un formulario de solicitud a un correo. Pero bueno lo único que necesito saber es como puedo capturar esos datos. Un ejemplo me pudiera servir de ayuda.

Add: el filtro es un plugin que se llama VPF Vehicle part finder

[image: imagen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He visto que el filtro envía los datos por GET en la url:

```
http://wc.wpinstinct.com/?make=6&model=48&year_id=55&engine=&category=17&s=&post_type=product&action=vpf-search
```

Entonces se podría capturar estas variables get cuando el usuario de click en "filtrar" o en "encuentra tu producto" y enviarlas a un correo.
Aquí una guía: https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/317.php

La otra opción seria capturar la información de esos campos por medio de javascript/Jquery cada vez que cambien y luego enviarla.

Aquí una guía: http://www.anerbarrena.com/jquery-change-1879/

Lo que no me queda claro es si el botón "encuentra tu producto" va a estar dentro del filtro o por fuera, en los productos.

Comment: Gracias Juan Mafla me sirvió muchísimo para guiarme , bueno lo que hice fue investigar un poco y con la ayuda de un amigo creamos lo siguiente: *Se creo en la carpeta functions.php la siguiente funcion : `function dameURL(){
$url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
return $url;
}`

Comment: Esa funcion me captura mi url cuando filtre mis datos y en otro archivo php cree un recorrido `$url = dameURL(); $vec_1 = explode('?', $url);
          $vec_2 = explode('/', $vec_1[0]); $bool = FALSE;
          foreach ($vec_2 as $str_vec ) { if($str_vec == 'product-category'){
           $bool = TRUE; }elseif($bool == TRUE){  echo $str_vec ?><br><?php ;  break; }
        } 
          $vec_2 = explode('&', $vec_1[1]);

          foreach ($vec_2 as $str_vec ) {
            $vec_3 = explode('=', $str_vec);
            echo $vec_3[0] . '-' . $vec_3[1] ?><br><?php ; 
          }`

Comment: Ese recorrido lo que hace es buscar primero mi categoría y luego filtrar dependiendo de si encuentra un ?  o / y luego me lista los resultados, dejare este código por si alguien le interesa ;).